# Bootstrap Navbar disappearing with smoothScroll

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Currently I have a bootstrapped navbar, which works completely fine, including mobile responsiveness, however one issue I just cant rectify is with the `nav-item`'s (headings)

The `nav-item`'s navigate to sections of the same page using `#`, and i have created a (click) listener function which `smooth` scrolls the navigation (animates it)

heres the .ts function:

```
 scrollToElement($element): void {
      $element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });
  }
```

heres the .html nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="'.'">MEX</a>-->
    <div class="logo-header">
        <a (click)="scrollToElement(hero)">
          <img src="assets/img/landing/hero/AEM%20Logo%20black.png" alt="logo" class="logo" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Step 3: Toggle the value of the property when the toggler button is clicked. -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler text-center" mat-button type="button" (click)="isMenuCollapsed = !isMenuCollapsed">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
  
    <!-- Step 2: Add the ngbCollapse directive to the element below. -->
    <div [ngbCollapse]="isMenuCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
      <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <!-- Step 4: Close the menu when a link is clicked. -->
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="scrollToElement(company)">Company</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="scrollToElement(research)">Research & Analysis</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" (click)="scrollToElement(pricing)">Pricing & Plans</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button routerLink="/login" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning login-btn">
              <mat-icon>login</mat-icon>Login
            </button>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

When clicking these `nav-items` the (click) listener does its job and animates the navigation to the requested section, the problem is however, the navbar completely disappears.

(**NOTE: adding `isMenuCollapsed = false` in (click) listener or .ts function does not solve the issue**

Comment: Adding the Bootstrap class `fixed-top` to your navbar doesn’t do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

giving `.navbar` `position: sticky !important;` within the component of the navbar will solve this issue, also using bootstrap class `fixed-top` resolves this similarly